# Clear animation after hover and using timer

Tags: jquery

First of all I would like to say hallo to all and I'm glad to be here. I read and learn a lot from you guys. Now I try to figure out a small problem but dont get the answer. May you have a good idea what I can add or change in the function lines.

Following works fine without errors on my php site...

I'm using this to lines in the Header:

```
../jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
../animate-colors-min.js"></script>
```

This is the div in the Body:

```
<div id="access"></div>
```

This are the CSS lines:

```
#access {
   background: #31363E;
   display: block;
   width: 50%;
   overflow: hidden;
   height: 22px;
   opacity: 0.8;
}
```

...and at last the Code for animating etc.:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#access').hover(function() {
    $.data(this, "timer", setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
    $(this).animate({backgroundColor:"#12121c", height:"+=113px"}, 500);
  },this), 1000));
  }, function() {
    clearTimeout($.data(this, "timer"));
    $(this).animate({backgroundColor:"#31363E", height:"-=113px"}, 500);
  });

});
```

Ok. I guess you can already see the problem. If I move my cursor over the div and dont feel like to wait 1 second and move the cursor from the div away, the div will do minimize his height. That's wrong and needs to be fixed.

If I wait 1 second or longer the div will do expand and after mouseout it will go back to the default height. That's just right.

I have no clue what to do and couldn't find some in other treats to fix it.

Hope you can understand my writing.

Comment: So basically you want... Once the mouse hovers over #access, wait 1 second, then animate. If the mouse leaves before 1 second, don't animate?

Comment: Yes that is right. You guys are quick. Problem is already solved. Was my first post. Next time I will be faster to answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sort hackish way to do this is to only shrink if the `div`'s height is above a threshold.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#access').hover(function() {
    $.data(this, "timer", setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
    $(this).animate({backgroundColor:"#12121c", height:"+=113px"}, 500);
  },this), 1000));
  }, function() {
    clearTimeout($.data(this, "timer"));
    if ($(this).height() > 22) {
      $(this).animate({backgroundColor:"#31363E", height:"-=113px"}, 500);
    }
  });

});
```

Here's a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/krispharper/MMBuh/).

Not sure if that meets your needs or not.

Comment: Yes, that is it. Problem Solved. Good Idea. Thanks for showing me the JS Fiddle too. It is a nice way to code quickly. Well done!